# What is the difference between prefrontal cortex and frontal lobe?

Tags: brain

They are both in the front. Looks like they're the exact same thing.

Is one part of the other?

What?

Why is it called prefrontral cortex? What does pre before frontal mean? Before front?

Comment: Please don't spam the same question, especially when you already got an answer and when your question was criticized for its simplicity and lack of effort. Prefrontal and frontal lobe are *not* the same thing, though prefrontal cortex is located in frontal lobe.

Comment: It's not the same question. Okay where else should I ask this sort of questions?

Comment: The answer says that prefrontal cortex is called such because it is behind the prefrontal bone that doesn't even exist in modern mamal. I seriously doubt the only answer. I think understanding etymology of certain anatomical term would help many people tremendously in remembering those terms.

Comment: Yes it is the same question. If you doubt an answer, address those doubts on the original answer, don't make a new identical question. Prefrontal cortex was named well before modern neuroscience by an anatomist who was familiar with animals of all sorts and apparently chose to make an analogy in naming, which is quite common in anatomy.